# how to manage a several asynchronous task before doing some action?

Tags: ios, swift

I am beginner in programming. I actually have my own answer of this questions and the app worked as I am expected, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to to this.

This check out action will be triggered after the user click `chechoutButton`. but before before this `chechoutButton.isEnabled` , I have to make sure 3 parameters are available (not nil). before doing this check out action, I need 3 parameters :

1. get user's coordinate from GPS.
2. get user's location address from Google Place
       API
3. Get current date time from server for verification.

method to get user location address from Google Place API will be triggered only if I get the coordinate from GPS, and as we know, fetching data from the internet (to take date and time) also takes time, it should be done asynchronously.

how do I manage this checkoutButton only enabled if those 3 parameters are not nil ? Is there a better way according to apple guideline to do this

the simplified code are below

```
class CheckoutTVC: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var checkOutButton: DesignableButton!


    var checkinAndCheckoutData : [String:Any]? // from MainMenuVC
    var dateTimeNowFromServer : String?
    var userLocationAddress : String?

    let locationManager = LocationManager()

    var coordinateUser : Coordinate? {
        didSet {
            getLocationAddress()
        }
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // initial state
        checkOutButton.alpha = 0.4
        checkOutButton.isEnabled = false

        getDateTimeFromServer()
        getCoordinate()



    }

    @IBAction func CheckoutButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    }




}



extension CheckoutTVC {



    func getDateTimeFromServer() {

        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        NetworkingService.getDateTimeFromServer { (result) in

            switch result {
            case .failure(let error) :
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                // show alert

            case .success(let timeFromServer) :
                let stringDateTimeServer = timeFromServer as! String
                self.dateTimeNowFromServer = stringDateTimeServer

                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
        }

    }


    func getCoordinate() {
        locationManager.getPermission()
        locationManager.didGetLocation = { [weak self] userCoordinate in
            self?.coordinateUser = userCoordinate
            self?.activateCheckOutButton()
        }
    }



    func getLocationAddress() {

        guard let coordinateTheUser = coordinateUser else {return}
        let latlng = "\(coordinateTheUser.latitude),\(coordinateTheUser.longitude)"

        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in


            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error) :// show alert
            case .success(let value) :
                let json = JSON(value)
                let locationOfUser = json["results"][0]["formatted_address"].string
                self.userLocationAddress = locationOfUser
                self.locationAddressLabel.text = locationOfUser
                self.activateNextStepButton()
            }


        }

    }


    func activateCheckoutButton() {

        if dateTimeNowFromServer != nil && userLocationAddress != nil {
            checkOutButton.alpha = 1
            checkOutButton.isEnabled = true
        }

    }


}
```

I manage this by using this method, but I don't know if this is the correct way or not

```
func activateCheckoutButton() {

        if dateTimeNowFromServer != nil && userLocationAddress != nil {
            checkOutButton.alpha = 1
            checkOutButton.isEnabled = true
        }

    }
```

Comment: Code reviews belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DispatchGroup` to know when all of your asynchronous calls are complete.

```
func notifyMeAfter3Calls() {
    let dispatch = DispatchGroup()

    dispatch.enter()
    API.call1() { (data1)
        API.call2(data1) { (data2)
           //DO SOMETHING WITH RESPONSE
           dispatch.leave()
        }
    }

    dispatch.enter()
    API.call3() { (data)
        //DO SOMETHING WITH RESPONSE
        dispatch.leave()
    }

    dispatch.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        finished?(dispatchSuccess)
    }
}
```

You must have an equal amount of `enter()` and `leave()` calls. Once all of the leave() calls are made, the code in `DispatchGroupd.notify` will be called.

Comment: Thank you very much jake for your information, I never learn about this thing. I just use 'dispatchqueue.main.async{}  to go back to main thread. what kind of topic should I learn to understand about these thing ? I mean I don't know where to start learning about, I need some keywords so i can learn step by step.  or do you have a recommended place to start learning this thing? really need your info. Thank You very much

Comment: Happy to help. I am no expert but I have found that to be the best way to do something like this. As far as keywords, I can't suggest much outside of just reading about "Asynchronous Swift Techniques".

Comment: DispatchQueues: https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1

Comment: DispatchGroups: https://www.raywenderlich.com/148515/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-2

Comment: That website has very good iOS guides, with clear explanations of what they are suggesting and why.